# What is the correct database structure to store historical data?

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design

I am designing a database in Sqlite that is intended to help facilitate the creation of predictive algorithms for FIRST Robotics Competition. On the surface, things looked pretty easy, but I'm struggling with a single issue: How to store past ratings of a team. I have looked over previous questions pertaining to how historical data is stored, but I'm not sure any of it applies well to my situation (though it could certainly be that I just don't understand it well enough).

Each team has an individual rating, and after each match that team participates in the rating gets revised. Now, there are several ways I could go about storing them, but none of them seem particularly good. I'll go through the ones that I have thought through, in no particular order.

**Option 1**:

Each Team has it's own table.It would include the match_id and the rating after the match was done, and could possibly also include the rating before.  The problem is, that there would be bordering on 10,000 tables. I'm pretty sure that's inefficient, especially considering I believe that it's also unnormalized (correct me if I'm wrong).

Table Name: Team_id

```
match_id | rating_after
```

**Option 2**:

Historical rating ratings for each team or stored in the match table, and current ratings are stored in the team table.  A simplified version of the team table looks like this:

Table : Team_list

```
team_id | team_name | team_rating
```

That isn't really the problem, the problem is with the historical data. The historical data would be stored with the match. Likely, it would be each teams rating before the match.

The problems I have with this one, are how tough of a search this will be to find the previous ratings. This comes from the structure of how FRC works. There are 3 teams on each side (forming what is known as an alliance) for a total of 6 teams. (These alliances are normally designated by the colors Red and Blue)
These alliances are randomly assigned ahead of time, and could include any team at the event, on either side.) In other words the match table would look like this (simplified):

Table: match_table

```
match_id | Red1 | Red2 | Red3 | Blue1 | Blue2 | Blue3 | RedScore | BlueScore | Red1Rating | Red2Rating | etc.....
```

So each team has to be included in the match info, as well as a rating for each team. If were to create more than one rating (such as an updated rating design that I want to do a pure comparison test with), things could get clogged really fast.

In order to find the previous rating for team # 67, for instance, I'd have to search Red1, Red2, Red3, Blue1, etc. and then look at the column that pertains to the position, all while being sure that this really is the most recent match.

Note: This might involve knowing not only the year of the data, the week it was taken in (I would get this data from a join with an event table), but the match level(whether it was qualifications or playoffs), and match #(which is not match_id).

Sure, this option is normalized, but it's also got a weird search pattern, and isn't easy from a front end standpoint(I might build a front-end for some of the data in the future, so I want to keep that in mind as well).

My question: **Is there an easier/more efficient option that I am missing?**

Because both designs feel somewhat inefficient. The first has too many tables, the other has a table that will have well over 100,000 entries and will have to be searched in a convoluted pattern. I feel as if there is some simple design solution that I simply haven't thought of.

Comment: Option 1 is terrible, won't scale, and will be a nightmare to query.  Option 2 is a step in the right direction, though I think you can normalize it a bit more by reducing the number of columns, and also adding a timestamp column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one sane answer:

```
team_rating:
team_id, rating, start_date, end_date
```

Making all ranges closed by using the creation date of the team as the first rating's start_date, and some arbitrarily distant future date (eg 2199-01-01) as the end_date for the current row. all dates being inclusive.

Queries to find the rating at any date are then a simple

```
select rating
from team_rating
where team_id = $id
and $date between start_date and end_date
```

and rating history is just

```
select start_date, rating
from team_rating
where team_id = $id
order by start_date
```

It's key that both start and end dates are stored, otherwise the queries are trainwrecks.

Comment: Thanks, this looks far better. I knew I was missing something obvious. My only issue with this, is that I don't actually have any start or end dates, plus, there are several matches in a single day. I only have the year it took place in, the week it did, and the order the matches came in. Should I just be placing arbitrary times in order to make is searchable?